# CCSprite is not using the same texture id

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures, ccsprite

I created two the same CCSpriteBatchNode, add in different CCLayer respectively.

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *mNode =      [param objectForKey:@"BatchNode"];

if (self =[super initWithTexture:mNode.texture rect:rect ])

{

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:[[allFrameCache objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] delay:frequencyFloat];
    CCAction* walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [self runAction:walkAction];

}
```

But it show:
2012-07-15 11:18:27.389 SanGuo_[21379:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'

I am a novice, research for a long time, I was very depressed, who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CCSprite is not using the same texture id

You can only add sprites to a sprite batch node which are using the same texture as the sprite batch node. This is the error you get when you try to add a sprite to a batch node with a different texture than the batch node.

Solution: make sure that sprite uses the same texture as the batch node.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the reason, is think you said, the start of a project, I think of the batch file by the same name no problem, the result is the cause,
CCSpriteBatchNode* BatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",name]] ;
All the CCSpriteBatchNode inside the Sprite node is 0 _0_0. PNG, 0 _0_1. PNG, 0 _0_2. PNG...... , but it is not the same as the photos, can't identify。
Endless said so much, don't know express consciousness yet? Thank you again!

Comment: Use a texture atlas maybe? This sounds like it could use one. Check out TexturePacker.